# Accessing EJB 3.1 from the client using the JNDI on port no 3700 glashfish Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1, openejb

I am using netbeans IDE 7.1.2 and I have created an EJB 3.1 Stateless Bean and implemented remote as well as local interfaces both and deployed it to the glassfish server 3.2.1 successfully...here is the Code

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___*CaseInfo.java****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
enter code here

package maxx;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless(name="CaseInfo",mappedName="CaseInfoBean")
public class CaseInfo implements CaseInfoRemote, CaseInfoLocal {

@Override
public String MyCaseMessageLocal() {
    return "Hello this is my Local message.";
}

@Override
public String MyCaseMessageRemote() {
    return "Hello this is my Remote message.Please Note that this message is comming from the remote";
}

}
```

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_**CaseInfoLocal.java****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

```
package maxx;

import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface CaseInfoLocal {

String MyCaseMessageLocal();

}
```

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*CaseInfoRemote.java****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
package maxx;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface CaseInfoRemote {

String MyCaseMessageRemote();

}
```

now i have accessed it from locally successfully and after it i have created
New Project>Java EE>Application Client project which is an desktop app hare i have accessed that bean successfully by adding jar file of bean module in to its library as a client Stub here is the some code

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___*Main.java****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
package applicationclient;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject;
import maxx.CaseInfoRemote;

public class Main {


public static void main(String arg[]) {

    try {
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                          "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
prop.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
prop.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700"); 

        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(prop);
        Object ref = ic.lookup("CaseInfoBean");
        CaseInfoRemote home = (CaseInfoRemote)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ref,
                CaseInfoRemote.class);
        System.out.println(home.MyCaseMessageRemote());

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

but when I am using this client accessing code go to New Project>java>java Application and writing here the same code so the problem showing that

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____*ERROR****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

```
run:
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory [Root exception is  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory]
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:674)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
at testcasebean.TestCaseBean.main(TestCaseBean.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:63)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:671)
    ... 4 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

---

and if i am removing properties lines of code so is giving this type of ERROR

run:
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:

```
java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:344)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at testcasebean.TestCaseBean.main(TestCaseBean.java:27)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

please tell how can i access this bean through using simple java desktop application because its no problem to using Java EE application Client but same code is giving these error

Comment: For connectivity problems at the client side, we normally don't require looking at the server-side code. Please edit your question and leave out only the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not following the instructions how to access remote EJB's - deployed on a GlassFish server - from *standalone* Java clients. It is not entirely trivial.

This should answer your question. In general, I am suspecting that what you're missing is the `gf-client.jar` file in your classpath. Follow the instructions and let us know:

http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#StandaloneRemoteEJB

Comment: has this changed much since javaee5 to now javaee7, or, pretty much the same?